# How to add and remove the same class using pure Js? Add class on "mouseover" event, delete on "mousedown" event

Tags: javascript, html

How to add and remove the same class using pure Js? Add class on "mouseover" event, delete on "mousedown" event.

HTML

```
    <section class="preview">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="preview__wrapper">
                <div class="preview__text">
                    <h1>Navigating the digital landscape for success</h1>
                    <div class="preview__descrp">Our digital marketing agency helps businesses grow and succeed online through a range of services including SEO, PPC, social media marketing, and content creation.</div>
                    <button onmouseover="result(1)" onmousedown="result(1)"  class="btn btn_prev">Book a consultation</button> // event button!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

SCSS

```
.btn{
    width: 231px;
    height: 68px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border-color: #191A23;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    &_prev{
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #191A23;
        width: 264px;
    }
    &_sh{
        box-shadow: 5px 5px darkgoldenrod;
    }
}
```

JS

```
let el = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function result(n){
    for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
        el[n].onmouseover = el[n].onmousedown = changeButton;
        function changeButton(event){
            if(event.type =='mouseover'){
                for(let i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
                    if(!el[n].classList.contains('btn_sh')){
                        el[n].classList.add('btn_sh')
                    }
                }
            } 
            if(event.type == 'mousedown'){
                for(let i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
                    if(el[n].classList.contains('btn_sh')){
                        el[n].classList.remove('btn_sh')
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
   
}
```

Comment: You can use JavaScript [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - `button.addEventListener('mouseover', myFunction);` - or css `:hover` animations.

Comment: You don't have to do those `.contains()` tests. If you add a class that is already in the class list, it will still be there only once.

Comment: Just a side note:  if your not doing mouse overs specifically for desktop use, then less than 30% of website users will even see this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code, pls try this way

js file

```
let el = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function result(n, eventType){
    for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      if(eventType === 'mouseover'){
          if(!el[n].classList.contains('btn_sh')){
             el[n].classList.add('btn_sh')
           }
      } 
      if(eventType === 'mousedown'){
          if(el[n].classList.contains('btn_sh')){
             el[n].classList.remove('btn_sh')
          }  
      }
    }
}
```

Html file

```
<section class="preview">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="preview__wrapper">
                <div class="preview__text">
                    <h1>Navigating the digital landscape for success</h1>
                    <div class="preview__descrp">Our digital marketing agency helps businesses grow and succeed online through a range of services including SEO, PPC, social media marketing, and content creation.</div>
                    <button onmouseover="result(0, 'mouseover')" onmousedown="result(0, 'mousedown')"  class="btn btn_prev">Book a consultation</button> // event button!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a JS here, just use `.btn:hover:not(:active)` CSS selector.

That means the style is active on the mouse hover but not when you click the button.

```css
.btn{
    width: 231px;
    height: 68px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border-color: #191A23;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}
.btn_prev{
   color: #fff;
    background-color: #191A23;
    width: 264px
}
.btn:hover:not(:active){
    box-shadow: 5px 5px darkgoldenrod;
}
```

```html
<section class="preview">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="preview__wrapper">
                <div class="preview__text">
                    <h1>Navigating the digital landscape for success</h1>
                    <div class="preview__descrp">Our digital marketing agency helps businesses grow and succeed online through a range of services including SEO, PPC, social media marketing, and content creation.</div>
                    <button class="btn btn_prev">Book a consultation</button> // event button!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help
I wanted to do it with hover , but I was interested in JS code)

Comment: What is the error here? html - code unchanged

let btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function toggleClassOnHover(event){
    const eventType = event.type;
    const n = Array.from(btn).indexOf(event.taget);
    if(eventType === 'mouseover'){
        btn.classList.add('btn_sh');
    }

    if(eventType === 'mouseout'){
        btn.classList.remove('btn_sh');
    }
}

btn.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('mouseover', toggleClassOnHover);
    button.addEventListener('mouseout', toggleClassOnHover);
})

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you can add as many buttons as you want, and each of them will have the hover and mouseout events applied, allowing you to customize their appearance when the mouse interacts with them.

html - code unchanged(in "button" tag i removed onmouseover and onmouseout)

```
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function toggleClassOnHover(event){
    const eventType = event.type;
    const n = Array.from(btn).indexOf(event.target);

    if(eventType === 'mouseover'){
        btn.classList.add('btn_sh');
    }

    if(eventType === 'mouseout'){
        btn.classList.remove('btn_sh');
    }
}

btn.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('mouseover', toggleClassOnHover);
    button.addEventListener('mouseout', toggleClassOnHover);
})
```